# Rails API: Most efficient way to update a list of associated records (many-to-many) with many additions/removals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Newbie question. When updating a list of associated records with many additions and removals, should I just replace the whole list or handle the additions/deletions separately?

How is this done in practice? I'm using Rails REST api with React.

Comment: Like so many things in programming, _it depends_. Neither is right or wrong, depends on your situation, how many records are there, is performance an issue, and so on and on...

Comment: @Eyeslandic I'm adding/deleting about 1-10 associated records and I'm not that concerned with performance.

Comment: Well, deleting and then inserting is definitely easier to code, just go with that then. You can do this inside a transaction just to be sure, if some delete or insert fails.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up handling the additions/deletions separately. Here's how I ended up doing it in Rails with Axios on the front end saving/deleting nested cast members on a movie project through a "roles" pivot table. Let me know if you know of a more efficient way.

**Front End**

```
// Excerpt from React Component for Project Edit page

// Adding cast members to project
axios
  .put(`/api/v1/projects/${projectId}`, {
    data: {
      attributes: project,
      roles_attributes: castPreSave // castPreSave is an array of "role" objects
    }
  });

// Removing cast members from project
axios
  .delete(`/api/v1/roles/${castToBeDeleted.join(',')}`); // castToBeDeleted is an array of "role" ids
```

**Rails**

The handled the additions as nested attributes on the main model...

```
// in ProjectsController
def update
  project = Project.find(params[:id])

  if project.update(project_params)
    render json: ProjectSerializer.new(project, options).serializable_hash
  else
    render json: { error: project.errors.messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

I handled the deletions directly on the pivot table...

```
// in RolesController
def destroy
  if Role.where(id: params[:id].split(',')).destroy_all
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: { error: role.errors.messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```